# How to stop the loop by providing loop result?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop

I have a requirement like i need get the parents list untill top most parent found ,If we reach the top most parent we will get his ref_by_id as null . so we can stop the loop .
     In this scenario i am not getting m at line(1)

```
    var u = "select ref_by_id from users where id=$1";
    var m = hey.ref_by_id;
    while (m !== null) {

        query(u, [m], function (er2, parentsList) {
            //line(1)
            if (parentsList[0].ref_by_id != null) {
                customObj.push(parentsList[0].ref_by_id);
                m = parentsList[0].ref_by_id;
            }
        })
    }
```

**Here how can i pass the result ID to m and again loop it untill it was null.**

Comment: Rewrite your `query`-function to return a promise (or wrap it in a function that does. Then you can [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your `query`-function is an asynchronous function, that returns the result via a callback that might be called sometime in the future. You must wait for that callback to be called before you continue. One way to solve it, is to make your own function call a callback with error and data:

```js
const myFakedata = {
  1: { ref_byid: null },
  2: { ref_byid: null },
  3: { ref_byid: 1 },
  4: { ref_byid: 3 },
  5: { ref_byid: 6 },
  6: { ref_byid: 4 }
};

// Fake query for test.
function query(sql, parameters, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback(null, [myFakedata[parameters[0]]]), 50);
}

function rersolveHierarchy(callback) {
  try {
    var path = [];
    var sql = "select ref_by_id from users where id=$1";

    function loop(currentId) {
      try {
        if (currentId === null) {
          //Loop finished
          return callback(null, path); // breaks the loop
        }
        currentId = +currentId;
        if (isNaN(currentId)) return callback(Error("currentId is not a number"));
        path.push(currentId);

        console.log("Search for", currentId);
        query(sql, [currentId], function(error, rows) {
          if (error) return callback(error);
          if (!rows || rows.length === 0) return callback(Error(`No rows for id ${currentId}`));
          if (rows.length > 1) return callback(Error(`Multiple rows for id ${currentId}`));
          loop(rows[0].ref_byid); // extract id for next loot iteration
        });
      } catch (error) {
        return callback(error);
      }
    }

    var hey = { ref_by_id: 5 }; // Test data
    loop(hey.ref_by_id); // Start loop
  } catch (error) {
    return callback(error);
  }
}

rersolveHierarchy(function(error, data) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);
  console.log(data.join(", "));
});
```

It works, but you will notice that you can't get the information out of the function, without a callback. And what about errors? If you want them to be reported out from the function, you need to add a callback for that too. And you need to ad try/catch for catch errors that might happen when you run your code, or your caller will never be notified. It  quickly becomes messy.

Another way to solve this is with [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async with await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).
A promise is a standardized way to handle asynchronous functions, and makes it easy to get the result or error later in the code. The `await` operator (added in ES2017)  waits for a promise to resolve, or throws an error if it was rejected. This makes it easier to use asynchronous functions.

Here is an example:

```js
const myFakedata = {
  1: { ref_byid: null },
  2: { ref_byid: null },
  3: { ref_byid: 1 },
  4: { ref_byid: 3 },
  5: { ref_byid: 6 },
  6: { ref_byid: 4 }
};

// Fake query for test.
function query(sql, parameters, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => callback(null, [myFakedata[parameters[0]]]), 50);
}


// Promise-wrapper for your query function.
// If there is an error the promise will be rejected
function pquery(sql, parameters) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    // calling your original query
    query(
      sql,
      parameters,
      // Callback function. if there is an error, reject the promise, otherwise resolve it
      (error, result) => (error ? reject(error) : resolve(result))
    )
  );
}

async function rersolveHierarchy(id) {
  var path, rows, currentId;
  const sql = "select ref_by_id from users where id=$1";
  path = []; // Start with empty array
  currentId = id;
  while (currentId !== null) {
    // make sure currentId is a number by using the unary plus operator
    currentId = +currentId;
    if (isNaN(currentId)) throw Error("currentId is not a number");

    // Check for infinity loop
    if (path.includes(currentId)) throw Error(`Loop detected: ${currentId}: ${path.join(",")}`);

    // What order do you want the items to be?
    // use "push" to add the latest to the end,
    // or "unshift" to add it at the begining
    path.push(currentId); //or path.unshift(currentId);

    console.log("Search for", currentId);
    rows = await pquery(sql, [currentId]); // Get next item

    // Check that only one row is returned.
    if (!rows || rows.length === 0) throw Error(`No rows for id ${currentId}`);
    if (rows.length > 1) throw Error(`Multiple rows for id ${currentId}`);
    currentId = rows[0].ref_byid; // extract id for next loot iteration
  }

  return path;
}

// Your function where you call resolveUserPath
async function myFunction() {
  const hey = { ref_by_id: 5 }; // Test data
  const path = await rersolveHierarchy(hey.ref_by_id);
  console.log("Path:", path.join(", "));
  return path;
}

// Always check for errors
myFunction().catch(error => console.error(error));
```